# html onchange super slow

Tags: javascript, html

this code worked for me super slow in chrome and firefox on a mac.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TextArea</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="txtarea">Input</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtarea" size="30" onchange="setText(this.value)"/>
        <p>Content Value</p>
        <label id="lbl_content"></label>
    </body>
    <script>
      let lbl = document.getElementById("lbl_content");
      function setText(value) {
        lbl.innerHTML = value;
      }
</script>
</html>
```

any reason why it is takes a couple of seconds ?

Comment: Maybe it's time to get a new mac! JUST JOKING! What do you mean by so slow? It works normally for me.

Comment: Use onkeyup instead of onchange

Comment: Okay so onchange on a input field needs it to loose the focus from the field. You will see once you type a letter and click outside the box it will show instantly. For text fields you need onkeyup events. onchange are usually for select boxes. Nice question. Never noticed this.

Comment: Please may you clarify your question? Have you measured how long things take? What about using "private mode"? Try turning off add-ons?

Comment: thanks for all your comments using onkeyup AND onchange did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work normally. If your intention is to change the value in the label whenever the user hit a key you should use onkeyup instead of onchange.
Because onchange is fired whenever the element loses focus, while onkeyup is fired whenever the user hit a key, **BUT** if a user input a value using autofill onkeyup wont be triggered however onchange will be triggered.
So I would recommend you to use both events.